# Style admin page in Yii

Tags: php, css, templates, yii

Im here again with a question about yii framework.

I've got a page under `views/myviewname/admin.php.`
I've got a page under `views/myotherviewname/admin.php.`
Now i want to give those pages another style. But how do i do that?

I've created a page under `themes/classis/views/myviewname/admin.php` and in that file i got this:

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

But i get an error. Because `$content` is not defined.

How do i style those pages? Would be nice if i can style all admin pages at once.

Comment: have you tried changing the layout in your controller like `$this->layout='myviewname/admin.php';` and have you se

Comment: @sush, it's definately getting the good document. But how do i echo the content from that page in the new style document? Because i get the error i know it's getting the file to load. So that works

Comment: Did class Controller extend the CController ?
Other question, how you rendered admin.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is undeniable that `$content` variable will be known as undefined, since it can only be used in `Layouts`, not `Views`.

As you probably know, if you already have set a theme for your application(in main config file by `'theme'=>'myTheme'`), Yii looks for that into `themes/myTheme` and all views will be rendered in `themes/myTheme/views/x/y.php` instead of `views/x/y.php`. Also, your layouts will be overridden by layouts located into `themes/myTheme/layouts`.

Now, lets assume that we want to create 2 themes:

1. DarkTheme
2. LightTheme

We should create structures like below:

```
+themes
    +darkTheme
        +views    
             +layouts
                 +main.php
                 +myLayout1.php
                 +myLayout2.php
             +myController
                 +myView1.php
    +lightTheme
        +views    
             +layouts
                 +main.php
                 +myLayout1.php
                 +myLayout2.php
             +myController
                 +myView1.php
```

We have a `main.php` which holds our base theme structure(skeleton), and 2 layouts named `myLayout1.php` and `myLayout2.php` respectively. Also we already defined a default layout into our base controller(Usually `Controller.php`) like below:

```
public $layout='//layouts/myLayout1';
```

Now, we have a main layout which shows everything inside `myLayout1` by default. We can change layout in out action like below:

```
$this->layout="myLayout2";
```

Also we can change application theme like below:

```
Yii::app()->theme="lightTheme";
```

> **Note:** Theme name is case-sensitive. If you attempt to activate a theme that does not exist, Yii::app()->theme will return null.

Above codes can be written into `beforeAction()` method or every action. Please note that, if you render `myView1`(`$this->render('myView1')`) and if the theme is set to `darkTheme`, Yii will render `themes/darkTheme/views/myController/myView1.php` instead of `views/myConteoller/myView1.php`.

---

To be more clear, `$content` will be used in layouts. Also, this is remarkable that, `$content` will be replaced by everything inside a view. So if you want to modify the whole page's schema, you must modify `main.php` layout. In front, if you want to modify the style of a view's content, you need to modify your layout.

Comment: can you help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185812/use-ajax-json-in-yii-framework