# Use ajax/json in yii framework

Tags: php, ajax, json, .htaccess, yii

Im trying to make a webshop in Yii framework. Now i want to unset a session when a user clicks on a icon.

I currently have it working that is sends a json call to a file, but the url in the json call is being rewrited by my htaccess i think.

JSON call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.glyphicon-trash').click(function(){
        $.getJSON("ajax/load.php?action=unset&element="+$(this).parent(), function(data) {
            alert(data.message);
        });
    });
});
```

Error i get:

```
GET http://mydomain.nl/my/path/to/site/ajax/load 404 (Not Found)
```

But it's not load, its load.php! But my htaccess rewrites that url..

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Other ways of implementing ajax calls in Yii are also good, only i need alot of explanation then.

Comment: Of course `.htaccess` will rewrite it. How about `CController::createUrl()` with defined route? It could be easily found in the tutorial.

Comment: Hi buddy, Why don't you pass url like this: `ajax/load/action/unset/element=...` ?

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl What is the actual url? I need how do you access that url in your browser?

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl buddy, It's quite unclear :( I mean the url you can access it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got this working now, i made a file under site view. Now i call it like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.glyphicon-trash').click(function(){
        var session = 'session';
        $.getJSON("<?php echo Yii::app()->baseurl; ?>/load?action=unset&session="+session, function(data) {
            location.reload(true); //<---- this one does not work tho...
        });
        setInterval(function(){location.reload(true);}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that it took so long (6 hours) for this question to get an answer. An alternative that works for me is `$.get("<?=$this->createUrl('controller/action', array('action'=>'unset'))?>");`

Answer (score 0):

You must not hardcode url's. You must use [`createUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail) or [`createAbsoluteUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createAbsoluteUrl-detail) as @Grimv01k recommends you. When in view or in controller you can do this by

```
$this->createUrl( 'foo/bar',array('id'=>321) )
```

Other ways:

```
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/baz/foo/bar'); // will use current controller
```

or

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('/baz/foo/bar')
```

**Edited**

So if you want

> to unset a session when a user clicks on a icon

you can do this in following way.

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    'click me to destroy session, mua-ha-ha',
    Yii::app()->createUrl( '/session/destroy' ),
    array(
        'type' => 'post',
        'dataType' => 'json',
        'data' => array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
        ),
        'beforeSend' => 'js:function(){
            console.log( $(this) );
            return false;
        }',
        'success' => 'js:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }',
    )
);
```

in `SessionController`:

```
public function actionDestroy () {
    if ( isset( $_POST['foo'] ) ) {
        Yii::app()->session->destroy();
        if ( Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest ) {
            $response = array(
                'status' => !Yii::app()->session->sessionID
            ) ;
            echo CJSON::encode( (object) $response );
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay and how do i use this with jquery? Because that's all PHP what you've written there..

Comment: I cannot use this. I need to set some jquery options first. Like i need to get some values from a table before i can unset the session. So your option can work, but not if u need text from other elements of the page.

Comment: You are wrong. You can collect your values in PHP and put them to `data` part (where foo and bar sit in my example). If data is not available at PHP level you can collect it from jQuery. All this array in `ajaxLink` is [AJAX options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). So you can add `beforeSend` there. I have updated my example by this part. Now in console you must see dump of clicked link object.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve these by core yii-ajax but if you want much work with ajax then you can use the core YII library with "renderPartial" ajax and widgets.

This is the core ajax call with yii

Add below line in your view.

```
<input type="hidden" id="baseUrl" value="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);?>">
```

Add below line in your js file.

```
function changeData(val1){

 var baseUrl = $('#baseUrl').val();
 var urlCI = baseUrl+'/Controller/actionMethod/;

 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlCI,
        data:{
            'action':'unset',
            'element' : 'someValue'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(response!=''){
                //do whatever work you want
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

}
```